# Code jam exercise python

Tags: python

I found out about Code Jam and decided to take a try on practice exercises.
So I started with year 2008 qualification round problem A: [Saving the Universe](https://code.google.com/codejam/contest/32013/dashboard#s=p0).

I found a solution for this problem from the achieves of Code Jam.

```
#!/usr/bin/python2.5

for case in range(input()):
    engines = set()
    for i in range(input()):
        engines.add(raw_input())
    s = 0
    t = engines.copy()
    for k in range(input()):
        q = raw_input()
        t.discard(q)
        if not len(t):
            s = s + 1
            t = engines.copy()
            t.discard(q)

    print "Case #%s: %s" % ((case + 1), s)
```

First of all I tried to pass the input from small file that is available for download. I opened the `.in` file with Wordpad, I copied everything and then ran the program and pasted the input to the shell. I got this error:

```
File "<string>", line 3
    for case in range(input()):
      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: `range()` needs an integer... so unless `input()` is supplying one then perhaps you want `range(len(input()))`.  It's hard to say without knowing exactly what you are putting into `input()`

Comment: You can't just paste the whole input file into the shell at once - each of those `[raw_]input` calls is expecting one entry. Try adding a prompt to each one (e.g. `for case in range(input("Enter number of cases: ")):` and entering each value by hand, to get to grips with what's happening.

Comment: @Jkdc this is designed to run in Python 2, so `input` will `eval(raw_input())` and convert the input to an integer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to type in shell:

```
$ python yourfile.py <A-small-practice.in
```

This way each line of file will be correctly read by your program ('<' passes the file to the program as input)